# How to add/rename configurations in Visual Studio (C++) Project Wizard?

Tags: visual-studio, wizard

I want to generate C++ projects with Visual Studio (2005/8/10) that have more configurations other than the default "Debug" and "Release". For example, I might want to additionally generate "Debug DLL" and "Release DLL", or rename them as those.

I've generated a custom project wizard, and tried adding/renaming the configuration names in the .vcproj file (found in the custom wizard project files), in the default.js file (found in the custom wizard project files), and even in using a custom common.js file (installed with Visual Studio).

None of if works. Added configurations are simply ignored. Renamed configurations cause the project generation to fail.

Am I asking the impossible? If so, does anyone know whether it's possible to manipulate the .vcproj "on the way out" in a post wizard step?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your solution properties.
2. Click "Configuration Manager..."
3. Under the "Active Solution Configuration" pull-down, click "<New>..." or "<Edit>..."